# sum of columns in another table - laravel

Tags: laravel

There's a loan table and loan_addition table. How can I sum the added_amt of loan_addition table and show them while returning loan table data?
loan_addition table

```
id   loan_id   added_amt
1       1        100
2       1        200
```

controller

```
$data = Loan::select('*')
->with('loanAddition') // how to sum all the columns of respective loan_id here
->get();
dd($data);
```

loan model

```
class Loan extends Model
{
    public function loanAddition() {
        return $this->hasMany(LoanAddition::class);
    }
}
```

LoanAddition model

```
class LoanAddition extends Model
{
    public function loan()
    {  return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class);  }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `withSum()` method as stated [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

```
$records = Loan::select('*')->withSum('loanAddition', 'loan_id')->get();
```

Then get the data like below:

```
$records->pluck('loanAdditions_sum_loan_ids');
```

### Update: for laravel below 8.12

```
Loan::select('*')->withCount(['loanAddition as loan_id'=>function($query){
        $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(loan_id) as loan_id"));
    }])->get()
```

Comment: Its throwing an error - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::withSum()

Comment: @AmritaStha this needs Laravel 8.12 and above

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Loan::select('*')
->with(['loanAddition',function($query){
      $query->select('sum(added_amt) as sum_added_amt')
 }]) // how to sum all the columns of respective loan_id here
->get();
dd($data);
```

or you can do is `$data->first()->sum('loanAddition.added_amt)` where you want sum

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(added_amt)'

Comment: Instead I've used the following as well but it return empty - $q->select(DB::raw('sum(added_amt) as sum_added_amt'));